# What's the Markdeep anchor for my heading?

Tags: anchor, markdowndeep

I have a Markdeep document that includes a heading:

```
### `PG::ConnectionBad - Is the server running locally`...
```

I want to link to this section from elsewhere in the document. It can be reached with `#toc4.2.16`, which is all very well, until I change the number of sections above it.

In GitHub it would be something like `#pgconnectionbad---is-the-server-running-locally`, but that doesn't seem to work. I know Markdeep generates anchors in a similar fashion, because I can reach a much simpler heading, `# Errors`, with `#errors`; how does it generate headings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, anchors for headings in Markdeep are generated by downcasing and removing spaces; punctuation and spaces are *not* converted to hyphens as they are on GitHub.

However, if you have inline code (`like this`) in a heading, this gets converted differently.

Each block of inline code seems to generate an anchor in the format `%EE%80%90nnnn%EE%80%90`, where `nnnn` is a base-36 number generated roughly sequentially - some numbers are skipped. (I have a feeling this is to keep them sequential but never generate a previously-used number for a different heading on the same page.)

You can find out the exact anchor by inspecting the source code, or (recommended) you can insert your own with `<a name="your-anchor-here"></a>` and use `#your-anchor-here` in your links.